# В чем преимущества выделения контроллера в mvc?

Tags: java, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

У меня сразу несколько вопросов по mvc. Спрашивать буду на примере игрушечной программки, которую специально для этого написал:

```
public class View implements Observer {

private Model model;
private IController controller;

private JLabel firstNumber = new JLabel();
private JLabel secondNumber = new JLabel();
private JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Model model = new Model();
            IController controller = new Controller();
            View view = new View();
            view.setModel(model);
            view.setController(controller);
            view.createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

public void setModel(Model model) {
    this.model = model;
    model.addObserver(this);
}

public void setController(IController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}

public void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("mvc train");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.getContentPane().add(createMainPanel());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private Component createMainPanel() {
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.add(firstNumber);
    mainPanel.add(secondNumber);
    mainPanel.add(resultLabel);
    JButton inc1 = new JButton("increment first");
    inc1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.execute("inc1", model);
        }
    });
    JButton dec1 = new JButton("decrement first");
    dec1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.execute("dec1", model);
        }
    });
    mainPanel.add(inc1);
    mainPanel.add(dec1);
    JButton inc2 = new JButton("increment second");
    inc2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.execute("inc2", model);
        }
    });
    JButton dec2 = new JButton("decrement second");
    dec2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.execute("dec2", model);
        }
    });
    mainPanel.add(inc2);
    mainPanel.add(dec2);
    return mainPanel;
}

@Override
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    firstNumber.setText("" + model.getA());
    secondNumber.setText("" + model.getB());
    resultLabel.setText("" + (model.getA() + model.getB()));
}

}
```

Это класс представления. Получается такая картинка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка increment first увеличивает на единицу первое число, increment second - второе, decrement first уменьшает первое число на единицу, decrement secomd - второе. В общем, после двух нажатий на increment first и одного нажатия на increment second получаем такую картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Два числа хранятся в модели. Вот она:

```
public class Model extends Observable {

private int a;
private int b;

public void incrementA() {
    a++;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public void incrementB() {
    b++;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public void decrementA() {
    a--;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public void decrementB() {
    b--;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public int getB() {
    return b;
}

@Override
public void addObserver(Observer observer) {
    super.addObserver(observer);
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

}
```

Мой контроллер:

```
public class Controller implements IController {

@Override
public void execute(String action, Model model) {
    switch (action) {
    case "inc1":
        model.incrementA();
        break;
    case "inc2":
        model.incrementB();
        break;
    case "dec1":
        model.decrementA();
        break;
    case "dec2":
        model.decrementB();
    }
}

}
```

Теперь вопросы.
Самый главный вопрос собственно в названии.

1. Чем нам помог контроллер? Код из веток case оператора switch в
   контроллере мог бы с таким же успехом находится в слушателях. На
   каждую ветку по слушателю. В итоге слушателей все равно приходится
   создавать, что бы вызвать метод контроллера. А потом в этом методе в
   операторе switch прописывать тот же самой код, что мог бы быть в
   слушателях. Может быть я вообще неправильно реализовал mvc?
   Подозреваю что именно так. Причем именно в части контроллера. Потому
   что по нему в сети мало информации. Если это так то прошу подсказать
   как правильно. Слышал что можно создавать контроллеры для каждого
   элемента (в данном случае для каждой кнопки). Но ситуация не сильно
   поменяется.
2. В моем примере все методы, которые вызывается в ветках case не имеют параметров. В реальных программах это скорее всего будет не так. Некоторые кнопки могли бы требовать вызовов методов с параметрами, причем с разным количеством параметров. Что делать в такой ситуации?
3. Где лучше вычислять самое правое число? В моем примере я делаю это в функции update(). Не лучше ли это делать в модели?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Контроллер помогает структурировать код. Весь код, реагирующий на пользовательский ввод, принадлежит контроллеру.

   Можно было бы всё слить в один класс, и делать всю логику в `OnClick`, и код получился бы наверное даже короче. Но вашей целью должен быть не самый короткий, а самый понятный и легко поддерживаемый код.
2. Мне кажется, ваша диспетчеризация команд по строкам — неправильна. Команды должны быть не строками, а объектами. (У нас же ООП, в конце-концов, да?) И вместо длинного свитча у вас должен быть всего лишь вызов `Invoke`. [Но это практика из MVVM, общепринятого паттерна в WPF, а традиции в MVC могут быть и другими.]
3. Вычисления принадлежат модели и только ей. Представление должно не выполнять работу модели (а сложение в реальной программе превратится в серьёзное, длинное вычисление), а лишь только отображать её.

Comment: спасибо большое, очень интересно. Можно по второму пункту уточнить? Нам нужно вызывать функции. Но мы можем обернуть их в классы? Они будут реализовать интерфейс MyListener, в котором будет один метод invoke(). То есть будет четыре класса, реализующих этот интерфейс: FirstIncrementer, SecondIncrementer и т.д. А метод execute в контроллере будет принимать параметр типа MyListener. И просто вызывать его метод invoke(). Тогда каждый слушатель подпихнет контроллеру нужную реализацию MyListener. Но что прописать в методах invoke() конкретных классов? По идее там должна быть работа с моделью

Comment: Но работа с моделью должна быть в контроллере.

Comment: получается, что в контроллере будет всего один вызовов, а весь обрабатывающий код опять же не в нем.. Хотя мы стремились как раз к переносы обрабатывающего ввод кода в контроллер. Не понимаю(

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Значит, эти классы (команды) должны быть частью контроллера. Так что весь обрабатывающий код всё равно в контроллере.

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, это паттерн Command?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: А фиг его знает, наверное. Я паттернами пользуюсь довольно мало, потому что они обычно либо достаточно негибкие (какого чёрта для того, чтобы конструировать объект отдельным _фабричным методом_, мне нужно заводить четыре класса?), либо тривиальны (что, есть на свете программист, который сам не додумался до _адаптера_?), либо уже реализованы в языке (например, _observer_ в C# встроен как `event`). Хотя крупные наподобие MVC/MVVM, да, пригождаются.

Comment: Тогда спрошу не на языке паттернов, а прям на конкретном примере (из моего вопроса). У меня будет интерфейс IController с методом execute, и его реализации: FirstNumberIncrementer, SecondNumberIncrementer и т.д. которые будут вызывать необходимы методы модели. Но как их нужную имплементацию IController подпихнуть нужной кнопке? То есть, FirstNumberIncrementer кнопке increment first и т.д.?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Ну, во время создания UI нужно привязывать команды. То есть кнопка будет знать свою команду, но не знать, что там внутри. И будет дёргать за неё по нажатию. Или не так, контроллер будет иметь `Map` кнопок в команды, и по кнопке находить нужную команду и запускать её. Не знаю пока, как правильнее. [Ну и наверное скорее `ICommand`, а не `IController`.]

Comment: а можно еще один вопрос? Сразу не подумал о нем, а выносить в отдельный вопрос слишком мелко. А где должна быть работа с базой данных? CRUD-запросы? В модели?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Да, в модели. Всё, что не относится к управлению и отображению — модель.

Comment: Можно еще один вопрос, пожалуйста? Задал его на англоязычном SO, но там молчат( а без этого понимания прям непреодолимый затык. А как разрабатывать View. Даже не в привязке к MVC, я понимаю, что в нем должно быть как можно меньше логики. Меня интересует другой вопрос. ГУИ у меня напичкан функциями. Получается очень большой класс. Но как его разделить? по какому принципу? Делать отдельный класс для левой панели, отдельный для правой, отдельный для центральной (у меня все 3 панели)? Не совсем правильно, наверное?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Как именно разрабатывать View — сильно зависит от используемого UI-фреймворка. Например, в WPF считается хорошим тоном дробить UI на мелкие компоненты. Например, если у вас UI состоит из трёх частей, то и правда разделить на три контрола. А то и на больше.

Comment: Я разрабатываю GUi на Swing. Руками все пишу, без редакторов форм. У меня много всплывающих окон еще есть, тоже довольно функциональных. Как в excel, примерно. Можно разработать основное окно единым классом, а все всплывающие окно отдельными классами? Или это плохая идея? Это точно последний вопрос) спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Можно. Нет никаких предпочтений, делайте как вам удобнее. Если заметите, что в одном окне слишком много кода/функциональности, попробуйте разбить его на контролы. Если наоборот все всплывающие окна одинаковы или почти одинаковы, попробуйте сделать один или несколько «универсальных» классов для этих. В общем, делайте как в нормальном программировании.